# Auto-set permissions when uploading to Amazon S3 with Transmit 4

Tags: amazon-s3, file-permissions

Does anyone know how to auto-set the read permissions for "World" upon upload of a file to Amazon S3 with Transmit? It is currently a two step process in my workflow:

1. upload the file
2. change permissions to allow the file to be read

I'd really to prefer to eliminate step 2 and just upload the file and have permissions set. Is there a way to create a profile that does this step for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into the Preferences > Rules menu, and that can be set there. Not a AWS thing.

Comment: I checked "Default File" and then chose Read: World in the S3 tab.

Comment: @LouieLouie has the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you may use Bucket Policies to configure bucket in a way that
all existing and new files will be publicly available.

Here is the bucket policy you need to apply:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You may use S3 Browser Freeware to apply Bucket Policy:
http://s3browser.com/working-with-amazon-s3-bucket-policies.php